# Are (let) and (lambda) equivalent in Common Lisp

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, common-lisp, let, on-lisp

I'm reading *On Lisp* by Paul Graham, trying to better understand the functional style of programming. In Chapter 3, he mentions that functional programs "work by returning values" rather than performing side effects. I don't quite understand the implications this statement makes on how to manipulate and represent intermediate results of a procedure. If a functional program returns a value, is capturing it using `(let)` equivalent to using a `(lambda)` function?

Here's an example showing the definition of a function, `(group)`, using a lambda function to capture the intermediate result. `(group)` takes a list, `src`, and a number, `n`, and subdivides the list elements into `k` groups of size `n`.

```
(defun group (src n acc)
  (funcall
    #'(lambda (back)
       (cond 
         ((consp back)
          (group back n (cons (subseq src 0 n) acc)))
         (t
          (reverse (cons src acc)))))
    (nthcdr n src)))
```

The last line of the function grabs the back partition of the list by taking the `(nthcdr n src)`. Then, this result is passed as an argument to a lambda function which decides how to process `src` conditioned on the argument. This is purely functional code, and has no side effects. On the other hand I could have defined `(group)` in the following way:

```
(defun group (src n acc)
   (let ((back (nthcdr n src)))
     (cond ((consp back)
            (group back n (cons (subseq src 0 n) acc)))
           (t
            (reverse (cons src acc))))))
```

where we use `(let)` to first bind the variable `back` to the `(nthcdr n src)`. I'm not sure how functional this version of `(group)` is because `(let)` binds variables to values in an imperative-like way.

Comment: I'm afraid this is going to come down to opinion. There is nothing non-functional about using `let`-binding, and other languages that are more purely functional, e.g., Haskell, use `let`-binding. Note that Paul Graham's style in _On Lisp_ is not particularly idiomatic Common Lisp (insofar as that is a real thing in CL). You would probably find more lispers opt for the second version using `let`.

Comment: They're equivalent. Behind the scenes, many lisp implementations convert `(let (x foo) ...)`  to `((lambda (x) ...) foo)`. The `let` is "syntactic sugar," i.e. syntax to make the bare lambda form more readable.  Whether it really is more readable is a religious issue :).  But they're both equally functional.

Comment: @adabsurdum: which to use may be opinion (but actually generally isn't if your goal is to write readable programs).  Understanding that they are equivalent and why they are is not.

Comment: Syntactically it adds another level of indirection by creating an anonymous function and calling it within a function. That seems overkill and is harder to comprehend by other humans (the computer probably doesn't care) and adds nothing to the return value of 'group' function.

Comment: By "imperative" style is usually meant an explicit manipulation of implicit state spread around your program's vars and data, and by "functional", the implicit manipulation of explicit state concentrated in one entity being passed along from function to function while being transformed. `Let` or `lambda` is just an irrelevant syntax issue. Except if it's `letrec`, which can *not* be simply replaced by lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, a way to regard `let` is that it is a more syntactically convenient form of a particular usage of `lambda`.

To clarify some notation, in Common Lisp several forms are equivalent.

- `(function (lambda (...) ...))` can be written as `#'(lambda (...) ...)` since `#'` is a reader macro.
- `#'(lambda (...) ...)` can then be written as `(lambda (...) ...)`, since `lambda` is a macro whose expansion is `(function (lambda (...) ...))`.
- Finally `(funcall (lambda (...) ...) ...)`, which is equivalent to `(funcall (function (lambda (...) ...) ...)` from above, can be written as `((lambda (...) ...) ...)`, as a special case of a compound form (see [3.1.2.1.2.4](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm)).

None of this is necessary in a Lisp-1, but in CL it is.

Below I am going to write `((lambda (...) ...) ...)` rather than the clunky `(funcall #'(lambda (...) ...) ...)` that I think Graham probably uses.

So, now, the important point:

**`(let ((x ...) ...) ...)` is entirely equivalent to `((lambda (x ...) ...) ...)`.**

Although it is not implemented this way in CL (`let` is a special operator), you can think of `let` as if it were a macro defined in terms of `lambda` like this.  In particular here is a definition for a macro called `allow` which is like `let` (you can't redefine `let` itself in CL of course, hence this name):

```
(defmacro allow (bindings &body decls/forms)
  `((lambda ,(mapcan (lambda (b)
                       (typecase b
                         (null '())     ;elide ()'s in binding list as special caee
                         (symbol (list b))
                         (cons
                          (unless (eql 2 (list-length b))
                            (error "mutant binding ~S" b))
                          (list (first b)))
                         (t
                          (error "what even is ~S" b))))
                     bindings)
      ,@decls/forms)
    ,@(mapcan (lambda (b)
                (typecase b
                  (null '())
                  (symbol (list 'nil))
                  (cons (list (second b)))
                  (t (error "what even is ~S" b))))
              bindings)))
```

And now, for instance, using a macroexpansion tracer:

```
> (allow ((x 1) (y 2)) (+ x y))
(allow ((x 1) (y 2)) (+ x y))
 -> ((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)
3
```

As I said, in CL `let` *isn't* defined like this as it is a special operator, but it *could be*, and there could be corresponding definitions of `let*` and so on.  Here is a definition of `allow*` which is `let*`:

```
(defmacro allow* (bindings &body decls/forms)
  (if (null (rest bindings))
      `(allow ,bindings ,@decls/forms)
    `(allow (,(first bindings))
       (allow* ,(rest bindings) ,@decls/forms))))
```

(And at this point I get to laugh at people who say 'macros with recursive expansions baaad, baaaad'.)

So from the perspective of the semantics of the language there is no difference at all: `(let (...) ...)` is entirely equivalent to `((lambda (...) ...) ...)`.  In particular, since any program involving `let` can trivially be rewritten to one using only `lambda`, and `lambda` is a purely functional construct, then `let` is *also* a purely functional construct.

There are then two differences in practical terms.

**Readability.**  This is the important one.  Programs are not just ways of instructing a machine to do something: they are a way of communicating your intent to *other human beings*.  For almost everyone (and I think, probably actually for everyone) it is easier to read code which says, in English

> let *x* be ..., and now ... things involving *x* ...

Rather than something which is extremely hard to even *write* in natural language, but might be

> *x* will have a value in here, and now ... things involving *x* ..., and the value is ...

And that's *even worse* when comparing

> let *x* be ... and *y* be ..., and now ...

with the really awful

> *x* and *y* will have values in here, and now ..., things involving *x* and *y* ..., and the values are ... and ...

That's just an awful way of writing something: the values are widely-separated from the variables being bound, there is no indication *which* value belongs to which variable when you finally reach them, and finally there's a serial dependency which is generally harder for humans to parse.

If you came across natural-language text written like this you'd correct it, because it's awful.  Well, that's what `let` does: it turns the hard-to-read `lambda` form to a much more understandable one, where the initial values are next to the variables.

**Possible historical ease of implementation.**  It is possible, I think, that it was once easier for a compiler if `let` was treated as a special case rather than as simply a macro which expands into a `lambda` form.  I am not *sure* about this, especially as I am fairly sure I have read somewhere I can't find just now that `let` *originated* as a macro, but it seems plausible as a reason that `let` is a special operator in CL.  Certainly I find it hard to imagine that it was not possible for a compiler to see `((lambda (...) ...) ...)` and compile *that* form in some optimal way (ie don't compile a function at all), even a very long time ago when compilers were made of mud and goose fat.

I think it is safe to ignore this second reason today.

Answer (score 3):

Many points to answer your questions :

First,

> In computer science, an operation, function or expression is said to
> have a side effect if it modifies some state variable value(s) **outside
> its local environment** -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))

So having local variables to process inputs doesn't mean you're not doing functional programming. What's important is the **deterministic** nature of functions you develop: for any set of inputs, functions should always return the same output corresponding to the inputs.

When you want to remove any use of local state, you're trying to do **purely functional programming** :

> Purely functional programming, a subset of functional programming
> which treats all functions as deterministic mathematical functions, or
> pure functions. When a pure function is called with some given
> arguments, it will always return the same result, and **cannot be
> affected by any mutable state** or other side effects. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

What's important here, is to know why you'd want to do functional programming :

> Proponents of purely functional programming claim that by restricting
> side effects, programs can have fewer bugs, be easier to debug and
> test, and be more suited to formal verification. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

I would also add important things like **lazy evaluation and graph reduction** (which should lead to automatic optimizations) :

> Lazy evaluation does not evaluate function arguments unless their
> values are required to evaluate the function call itself.
>
> The usual implementation strategy for lazy evaluation in functional
> languages is **graph reduction**. Lazy evaluation is used by default
> in several pure functional languages, including Miranda, Clean, and
> Haskell. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

Common Lisp can do lazy evaluation but using a framework like [CLAZY](https://clazy.common-lisp.dev/).

With functional programming, [concurrency is easy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195718/functional-programming-right-ideas-about-concurrency-and-state) because this paradigm avoids mutable state.

So to come back to your case, both `group` implementation use a local variables (the argument to your lambda is a local variable when you funcall it). Both use tail-recursion which is a good thing and remove a dependance to the capacity of the call stack.

The problem is that the local variable `back` in both implementations make an implicit dependance of your code to the limits of the system they run into, because `back` could be quite large.

If you know the maximum size of your input in advance and that it can be stored entirely in memory, then no problem to use those implementations. But if your input is some exabytes of data, you'd better use streams and [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32957760/3673) and reduce the local state to an integer (the number of elements in the current group you're building) instead of storing entire sequences and subsequences. That way you can distribute the load and have concurrency, thanks to Functional Programming.

Comment: `back` is no worse than `src` itself, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot personal taste, I would say.
Since `let` itself is mostly anyway implemented by `lambda`.
`lambda` arguments are local variables just as `let` is one.

```
(let ((a 1))
  a)

;; is equivalent to:
((lambda (a) 
   a)
 1)
```

I think it becomes rather interesting, if you use `let*`, since now you can sequentially use the stored and renamed intermediate values.
Nesting lambdas in contrast would be very bulky and difficult to understand. Because as you see - the input for the lambda comes at the very end of the lambda call ...

I like to use `let` especially, when mutating a variable or variables
using `setf` over a procedure or loop.

```
(let ((result '()))
  (loop for i in '(1 3 7 11)
        do (setf result (cons i result)))
  result)
;;=> (11 7 3 1)
```

Of course, this case is a very silly example (and could be expressed much more succinct without using `let`) but the procedure which is used for `setf`ing could be much more complicated.

This silly example would be expressed as `lambda` - tail-call recursively (I will use `defun` to name the `lambda`):

```
(defun myfun (lst &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null lst) acc)
        (t (myfun (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))))

(myfun '(1 3 7 11))
;;=> (11 7 3 1)
```

I think `let` is less verbose and is useful especially when one has several of such variables which will be mutated.

Probably when the variable which holds the results should be prominent, a `let` expression is better,
while if the procedure should be more emphasized - and be reusable - then the `lambda` or `defun` should be used - which gives the procedure a name.

But of course you could wrap a `lambda`/`defun` around a `let` expression to give the procedure a name ...